# Asp.net ftp site does not seem to correlate with the live site

Tags: asp.net

Looking at the code for a site in ftp and what is on the live site and they don't really match. Close, very close but no match. My Asp knowledge is limited. The code looks simple enough. I can change it locally and it works fine. No change in the ftp does anything on the live site. Which to me should be impossible. So does asp code look a lot different in ftp then javascript, php, or html. Could this be something that happens with compiling or could I simply be looking at the wrong site?

Comment: In ASP.NET application, code behind files are compiled into a single DLL file.

Comment: Thanks, I found some DLL files in there. Now will see what I can do with them.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely your looking at the wrong site.  By moving code to a FTP does not change the code.  Your code however could be minify which means its compiled to run faster on an FTP?

Enter some JavaScript on this site to minify it and let me know if that is what the code looks like.

http://jscompress.com/

Are you running it in IIS?

If so you might have it configured incorrectly.

Comment: Minifying JavaScript is not equivalent to compilation and does not make it "run faster".

Comment: Thanks for the link. Don't think minified would stop me from changing the live site.